# does binding param strip out underscores?

Tags: php, mysql

I used the following function:

```
function update_value($table, $field, $value, $type, $where1, $value1, $where2=NULL, $value2=NULL, $where3=NULL, $value3=NULL) {

$rows = array();
global $conn;
connect();  
$value1 = "'" . $value1 . "'";
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET $field =? WHERE $where1 = $value1";

$bind1 = "'" . "$type" . "'";

if ($where2 != NULL) {
    $value2 = "'" . $value2 . "'";
    $sql .= " AND $where2 = $value2";

}
if ($where3 != NULL) {
    $value3 = "'" . $value3 . "'";
    $sql .= " AND $where3 = $value3";
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


$stmt->bind_param($type, $value);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
}
```

...to update the username field of a table (making sure it's a string before updating via the above function). I tried updating with a string followed by an underscore but when it showed up in the table the underscore had disappeared.

I'm new to binding parameters, is there certain things it strips out? If so I'd like to know exactly what so I can use preg_match to catch them before it updates and alert the users.

Comment: *"does binding param strip out underscores?"* - *"I tried updating with a string followed by an underscore but when it showed up in the table the underscore had disappeared."* - Your question's title should be more like *"WHY does binding param strip out underscores?"*

Comment: binding doesn't change the data you're submitting. if you had underscores before, they'd be there after. however, you are STILL vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) because you're putting "external" data directly into the query string.

Comment: The function is just for me. I'll sanitize the data before putting it into the function. So it shouldn't be stripping out underscores? Any idea why it would be?

Answer (score 0):

The way you manipulate with data is very dangerous.

But just to fix some potential issues keeping your logic you should surround all potential table and column names with backticks and prepare values with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:

```
$val1 = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($value1) . "'";
$sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET `$field` = ? WHERE `$where1` = $val1";

if (!empty($where2)) {
    $value2 = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($value2) . "'";
    $sql .= " AND `$where2` = $value2";

}
if (!empty($where3)) {
    $value3 = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($value3) . "'";
    $sql .= " AND `$where3` = $value3";
}
```

Comment: The problem with using the real escape string is that I need to convert it somehow when I read from the table.

Is there a way to do that?